# Yet Another Holiday Rebus

Tags: rebus, seasonal

I'm back with another holiday rebus!!! This one is slightly more confusing, but you guys will figure it out, I'm sure.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the answer is

> For it is in giving that we are happy.

Explanation:

> The first image represents the word "more". Removing m and e, we can add the f at the beginning to get **for**. Next are the literal words **it is in**. The second image represents "give". Ignoring the e, we add "ing" to get **giving**. The third image is of a hat. If we add the t at the beginning, we get **that**. I'm not as certain about the rest, but I think it is **we are happy**.

Note:

> There is a similar quote, "For it is in giving that we receive", by St. Francis of Assisi, but the final clues appear to mean something else.